Trouble connecting to NAT and using Aircrack-ng in Kali Linux on VirtualBox
I am connected to my VirtualBox through Wi-Fi and have selected the bridged adapter in Kali Linux. However, when I try to connect using NAT, it is not working. Additionally, I am having problems with Aircrack-ng and network commands in Kali Linux. I cannot scan or hack any Wi-Fi networks. Please help me solve this issue.

Neither bridging nor NAT is what you need when you need to use your wifi device as anything but a packet-transporting interface – also, NAT and bridged device is mutually exclusive, so whatever you're describing doesn't work like that.
So, you need to completely pass through control of the USB or PCIe network card (not just the network interface) to your Kali VM. Obviously, you can't use the interface for networking purposes at the same time.
